# how to get only one output from a "for"

Tags: python, list

Hi I'm learning Python and I am trying to code the below random number picker:

```
import random
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
user_input = input("Do you want to roll the dice?(y/n)")

if user_input == ("y" or "yes"):
    user_input2 = input("Select a number between 1 and 6: ")


    if int(user_input2) in dice:
        print("Number with in the rage!")

        for x in dice:
            if int(user_input2) <= 6:
                print("Your random number is: ", random.choice(dice))
            else:
                print("The inserted number is not within the range")
                
    else:
        print("Exiting Game!")
    
        
else:
    print("Not entering the game...")
```

So it will compare the user input against the objects in the list to determine whether the user is entering a valid number to proceed to "roll the dice", the thing is that the output Im getting is:

```
Number with in the rage!
Your random number is:  4
Your random number is:  2
Your random number is:  1
Your random number is:  1
Your random number is:  4
Your random number is:  6
```

A new line/result for each number in the list, but I just want 1 result not six, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Get rid of `for x in dice:` - it is not clear why you have that loop at all - you are looping over the elements of the list `dice` so it runs 6 times (although you are not actually using the loop variable `x`, so every iteration does the same thing aside from the random number).

Comment: What is the point to writing a loop if you only want to do something once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
user_input = input("Do you want to roll the dice?(y/n)")

if user_input == ("y" or "yes"):
    user_input2 = input("Select a number between 1 and 6: ")

    if int(user_input2) in dice:
        data = []
        print("Number with in the rage!")

        for x in dice:
            if int(user_input2) <= 6:
                data.append(random.choice(dice))
            else:
                print("The inserted number is not within the range")
        print("Your random number is: ", data )
                
    else:
        print("Exiting Game!")
    
        
else:
    print("Not entering the game...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.randint()`:

```
import random
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
user_input = input("Do you want to roll the dice?(y/n)")

if user_input == ("y" or "yes"):
    user_input2 = int(input("Select a number between 1 and 6: "))
    if user_input2 in dice:
        print("Number with in the rage!")
        print("Your random number is:", random.randint(1, user_input2+1))
    else:
        print("The inserted number is not within the range")
        
else:
    print("Not entering the game...")
```